# How to get __metatable function to be called?

Tags: lua, metatable, meta-method

## My goal

Get `getmetatable` to return the return value of the function assigned to the `__metatable` field.

Code:

```lua
local x, m = {}, {__metatable = function() return nil end};
setmetatable(x, m);
io.write("Let's get the metatable:", tostring(getmetatable(x)), "\n");
```

But I'm getting the actual function rather than return.

So how do I get it to be called so I can get nil? So it seems like it has no metatable?

Comment: You can redefine global function `getmetatable()` to change the logic if the argument equals to your `x`

Comment: You could approximate that behavior by setting `__metatable` to `false`

Comment: Hiding the existence of a metatable is futile if `setmetatable` is also available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rewrite getmetatable to work the way you want it to ;)

```lua
do local getmetatable = getmetatable
   function _G.getmetatable(tab)
      local meta = getmetatable(tab)
      if type(meta)=='function' then
         return meta(tab)
      else
         return meta
      end
   end
end
```

---

Alternatively, you could just set `__metatable` to false. This would work for code written like `if getmetatable(foo) then`, but would break to code like `if getmetatable(foo) == false`. Arguably, the first is the one you *should* use, but there's likely someone out there doing the second one.

That'd also hint to the user that there *is* a metatable, it's just none of their busyness to mess with it.